# How to find the range of my projectile motion with python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, physics

I'm simulating projectile motion of multiple angles with Python. This is an almost completed code except for the fact that I also need to show the range of each projectile. Any idea of how I should do it?

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import math 

#theta=pi/3
V=38.5 #speed
t=np.arange(0,19,0.1)

angle = math.pi/12
angle_list=[]

while angle < math.pi/2:
    x=V*np.cos(angle)*t
    y=V*np.sin(angle)*t+(0.5*-9.8*t**2)
    plt.ylim([0,80])
    plt.xlim([0,170])
    print(x,y)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    angle_list.append(rf'{np.rad2deg(angle):.0f}$\degree$')
    angle+=math.pi/12
    

plt.xlabel("range")
plt.ylabel("height")
plt.title('Projectile Motion With Multiple Angles')
plt.legend(angle_list)
plt.show()
```

Picture of the graph:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by range? the final x? what do you mean by show?  print it?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant, finding the final x of each projectile and printing them

Comment: so isn't it just printing last `x` by `print(x[-1])`?

Comment: @LiorCohen not exactly, the graph extends to the negative side which is not shown here. `t` is not based on time of flight but rather a general extended length of time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to find the zero crossing point i.e the max `x` for which `y > 0` and that gives you the range which can be used to annotate the graph as following-

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

# theta=pi/3
V = 38.5  # speed
t = np.arange(0, 19, 0.1)

angle = math.pi / 12
angle_list = []

while angle < math.pi / 2:
    x = V * np.cos(angle) * t
    y = V * np.sin(angle) * t + (0.5 * -9.8 * t ** 2)
    plt.ylim(0, 80)
    plt.xlim(0, 170)
    # print(x, y)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    zero_crossing_idx = np.argwhere(y > 0)[-1]
    plt.annotate('{:.2f}'.format(x[zero_crossing_idx][0]), (x[zero_crossing_idx//2], y[zero_crossing_idx//2]+0.5))
    angle_list.append(rf'{np.rad2deg(angle):.0f}$\degree$')
    angle += math.pi / 12

plt.xlabel("range")
plt.ylabel("height")
plt.title('Projectile Motion With Multiple Angles')
plt.legend(angle_list)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you. What does the [-1] after zero_crossing_idx = np.argwhere(y > 0) mean?

Comment: Also, as I tried to the print the ('{:.2f}'.format(x[zero_crossing_idx][0]) and see what they are, I found that it printed the exact values being shown in the graph, so what does (x[zero_crossing_idx//2], y[zero_crossing_idx//2]+0.5) do exactly?

Comment: `[-1]` gives the index in the array where the projectile meets the ground again. while this part`(x[zero_crossing_idx//2], y[zero_crossing_idx//2]+0.5)` is just calculating the peak point of the projectile and moving it in y-direction a bit upwards to position the `range` number on to the graph

Comment: Got it! and what does the [0] after '{:.2f}'.format(x[zero_crossing_idx] means?

Comment: it just accesses the value at 0th index. try without it and see the difference

Comment: oh ok. Another question, since np.argwhere(y > 0)[-1] has y>0, does it mean that the zero_crossing_idx is actually a number slightly larger than 0, which isn't exactly when y is touching the x-axis ?(since it would be exactly 0 then)

Comment: Yes, you're right. If you want the exact range it has to be calculated by a formula.

Comment: ohh got it. One more thing that confuses me: does x[zero_crossing_idx][0] means x times the number in the zero_crossing_idx?